# Webpack: How to export directly to global (without .default) containing stylesheet imports?

Tags: javascript, webpack

## Context

I have a `webpack.config.js` like this:

```
/* Something here */

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    library: 'MyClass',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: `package.js`
  },
  ...
}
```

My `./src/index.js` looks like this:

```
import MyClass from 'src/myClass'
import 'src/myStyle.css'

export default MyClass
```

## Problem

While this works fine, it exposes `MyClass` class to `window` object as:

```
console.log(window.MyClass)
=> Module {default: ƒ, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

This way, I cannot invoke my class by using:

```
new MyClass();
=> TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor
```

I have to invoke it like:

```
new MyClass.default();
=> MyClass { ... }
```

I can solve the problem by doing something like this in my `./src/index.js`:

```
const MyClass = require('src/myClass')
module.exports = MyClass

/* in browser */
new MyClass()
=> Good, works fine
```

However, this way, I cannot `import` my stylesheet:

```
const MyClass = require('src/myClass')
import 'src/myStyle.css'

module.exports = MyClass
=> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

**Edit**

The following way also solves the problem, but is done without an `export`:

```
/* webpack.config.js */
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    /* Need to remove library related props */
    // library: 'MyClass',
    // libraryTarget: 'window',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: `package.js`
  },
  ...
}

/* ./src/index.js */
import MyClass from 'src/myClass'
import 'src/myStyle.css'

window.MyClass = MyClass
```

## Question

Is there a way in Webpack for me to `export` a module directly to global without having to invoke with `.default` *and* at the same time `import` a stylesheet in the entry file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `output.libraryExport` in your `webpack.config.js`. ([ref](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport))

Along with `output.libraryTarget` set to `umd`, `output.libraryExport` tells Webpack which property to be exported as the global variable named by the `output.library`.

In your case, in addition to your original configuration, set `output.libraryExport` to `default` is equivalence to append the following snippet after your compiled code.

```js
window.MyClass /*output.library*/ = module.exports.default /*output.libraryExport*/
```

The configuration will be as follows.

```js
/* Something here */

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    library: 'MyClass',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default',  // export the default as window.MyClass
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: `package.js`
  }
}
```

Have a try in the console.

```
> window.MyClass
class {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is only designed to run in the web browser only why not just update `window` explicitly:

```
import MyClass from 'src/myClass'
import 'src/myStyle.css'

window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

I think this is a lot clearer than using indirection.

Comment: It is indeed a solution I never thought of. But I'm more interested in using the `export` syntax. What if it is also designed for server environment?